# How to write powershell script to get the status of website url based on other website url

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

Can someone please help!

With my below Power Shell script, I'm able to get the status of all the URL's. With this, though google URL is not working (I gave wrong url intentionally), script is running 3 times which is of no use.

My condition is... My gmail and signin links should work only if google link is working. And my signin link should work only if gmail link is working. If not, it should end the script by sending email with error code (i'm using this try catch block to store this error code).

This is my code.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

[array]$URL_LIST_FILE = Get-Content -Path 'path/of/file'

$URL_LIST = @($URL_LIST_FILE)
foreach ($URL in $URL_LIST)
{
    try {
        $RESPONSE = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URL -ErrorAction Stop
        $RESPONSE_CODE = $RESPONSE.Statuscode
        Write-Host "Response Code: $RESPONSE_CODE" -ForegroundColor Green
        if ($RESPONSE_CODE -eq 200)
        {
            Write-Host "$URL is Working." -ForegroundColor Blue
        }
    }
    catch {
        $ERR = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
        $ERR_CODE = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
        Write-Host $ERR_CODE $ERR -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "$URL is not working. Sending Email..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        #Send-MailMessage -To to@somemail.com -From from@somemail.com -Subject "subject is here" 
    }
}
```

My file contains:

```
www.google.com                        - Google link
www.gmail.com                         - Gmail link
www.accounts.google.com/gmail         - Signin link
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try get the error captered in the else statement.

```
if ($RESPONSE_CODE -eq 200)
        {
            Write-Host "$URL is Working." -ForegroundColor Blue
        }
Else {Write-Host "$URL is not Working." -ForegroundColor red}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest... I don't understand your intention

Many endpoints are independent of each other cause that are other services.

Nevertheless...

If you want to avoid subsequent calls to an endpoint which was already classified as unreachable by previous calls for an upper domain level or site on same host, then you should build a nested hashtable / maybe list.

Since this it not done by a simple one liner, maybe you can provide some more details about your intention. 
(but to classify something like gmail.com to be unreachable for google.com subdomains will be difficult) ;)